# ASP.NET MVC 3: Reuse the same form in all the web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel, partial-views

I have a Razor ASP.NET MVC 3 web site.

I have a web site with this structure for all pages:
  - header with search text box in top-right
  - body
  - footer

I would like to have two distinct views with their own specific model.
I would like to have two distinct method: one for the search and one for the body actions.

How to organize this?
If I use two partial views I have to pass SearchModel around all pages for all controllers for all methods.

How to deal with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to reuse your search form:
First is to use `@Html.RenderAction()` at `_Layout.cshtml` that will render your search form to view.
Second is to use `@Html.RenderPartial()` at `_Layout.cshtml`, and model will pass to view throught ViewBag object or ViewData dictionary from global action flter.

Answer (score 1):

For the search box in your view you can use `@Html.Action` to call a child action allowing it to build the SearchModel / search view independently from the current action.

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx